# How to add 10 pixels to a dynamic top position in CSS using SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

I have two elements, A and B, with the exact same properties, class and ID, but their top property is different. I cannot add classes, IDs, or change the element. Whatever applies to element A applies to element B. I essentially want select this element via CSS selectors and re-assign their top property using !important, and by taking the dynamic value of their top property and adding 10 pixels to it. Essentially moving each element 10 pixels from the top.

Thanks!

Comment: Dynamic as in it is getting modified by JavaScript?

Comment: Are you asking if you can get the padding-top as would have been defined by other rules, and then calc off that? If so, you can't do that.

Comment: Dynamic as in this element could be on multiple pages. Maybe dynamic isn't the right word for it since the top property won't always change. It will just be different from page to page @cimmanon

Thanks!

Comment: Basically take the the top property, which could be 100px or 200px and add to both of them 10px, so the elements would thus be 110px and 210px @DylanWatt

Comment: SASS would be generated into long before it was on the page to know about other rules to look at. It's not a browser technology, it's just a handy preprocessor. It can't do anything that straight CSS couldn't do, and CSS rules can't do anything based off of each other.  I'd look into whether you can "cheat" by using a margin top, padding top, css-transform, wtc.

Comment: It's a select menu, so not margin top or padding top. Do you have any recommendations for css-transform? @DylanWatt

Comment: `transform: translate(0px, 10px);` http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: That's it! Thanks! @DylanWatt

Comment: You should update this topic with an example of your DOM with two or more parent elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment chain:

SASS would be generated into css long before it was on the page to know about other rules to look at. It's not a browser technology, it's just a handy preprocessor. It can't do anything that straight CSS couldn't do, and CSS rules can't do anything based off of each other. I'd look into whether you can "cheat" by using a margin top, padding top, css-transform, etc.

EG:`transform: translate(0px, 10px);`